# VBA Do not prompt to Save Macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro that makes prompts the user to save the changes to the Personal Macro Workbook each time it is run. Is there any way to disable this message?

I have tried this: `ThisWorkBook.close SaveChanges:=False`but it still prompts the message

[image]

Comment: Are you making changes to the file in your code? You could try `ThisWorkBook.Saved=True` before closing.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no changes made to the Personal Macro Workbook, or if you don't want changes to be made, just use `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True`. You can also try setting `Application.DisplayAlerts` to `False`, call a close to the workbook, and turn the `DisplayAlerts` to `True` again.

The above can be seen [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213428).

Answer (score 0):

If you have formulas in a worksheet in the personal macro workbook, Excel will automatically recalculate them every time the workbook is opened and this constitutes a change which Excel will ask you to save.

Get round it by not putting formulas in the worksheets in the personal macro workbook. If your macro requires formulas, you could always create these in another workbook which your macro can access when it runs.